# Automapper projection fails with nullable properties

Tags: c#, automapper

Automapper version: 6.0.2

I have two classes `InternalEntity` as my data source and `PublicEntity` exposed as API. I'm trying to access `InternalEntity` via `PublicEntity` projection using `UseAsDataSource` method.

The thing is that internal `bool` property mapped to public `Nullable<bool>` property.

It fails when I'm using this property in projection e.g. calling OrderBy on that. Please see sample below for details.

Can I set up projection rule for bool? -> bool somehow?

Here is code sample:

```
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Sample
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public class PublicEntity
        {
            public string PublicName { get; set; }
            public bool? Active { get; set; }
        }
        public class InternalEntity
        {
            public string InternalName { get; set; }
            public bool Active { get; set; }
        }

        private static IMapper mapper;

        private static void SetupMapping()
        {
            var mc = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<InternalEntity, PublicEntity>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.PublicName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.InternalName));

                // setup bool? -> bool projection somehow
            });

            mc.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            mapper = mc.CreateMapper();
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SetupMapping();

            try
            {
                IQueryable<PublicEntity> resultable = DataSource()
                    .UseAsDataSource(mapper)
                    .For<PublicEntity>()
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Active);

                resultable.ToList()
                    .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.PublicName));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        private static IQueryable<InternalEntity> DataSource()
        {
            return new List<InternalEntity>()
            {
                new InternalEntity(){ InternalName = "Name 1", Active = true},
                new InternalEntity(){ InternalName = "Name 3", Active = true},
                new InternalEntity(){ InternalName = "Name 2", Active = false},
            }.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Sample.Program+InternalEntity,System.Boolean]]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Sample.Program+InternalEntity,System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]]]' of method 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[Sample.Program+InternalEntity] OrderBy[InternalEntity,Nullable`1](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Sample.Program+InternalEntity], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Sample.Program+InternalEntity,System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]]])'
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arg, ParameterInfo pi)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateArgumentTypes(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, ReadOnlyCollection`1& arguments)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at AutoMapper.Mappers.ExpressionMapper.MappingVisitor.GetConvertedMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at AutoMapper.Mappers.ExpressionMapper.MappingVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Impl.SourceInjectedQueryProvider`2.ConvertDestinationExpressionToSourceExpression(Expression expression)
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Impl.SourceInjectedQueryProvider`2.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Impl.SourceSourceInjectedQuery`2.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sample.Program.Main(String[] args) in xxxx\Program.cs:line 48
```

Comment: You could try to add `.ForMember(dest => dest.Active, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => (y == null) ? false : true );`

Comment: @KeyurPATEL It does not help, what is the reason to check if source object is null?

Comment: Ah I missed the actual check for `.Active`, how about `.ForMember(dest => dest.Active, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => (y.Active == null) ? false : true );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find solution myself. One or the other line will do nicely:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Active, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (bool?)src.Active))

.ForMember(dest => dest.Active, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new Nullable<bool>(src.Active)))
```

Those lines are semantically equivalent.

Note that those lines produce different expression trees, which may become important if you are going to parse expression trees.

Answer (score 2):

This error sounds logical - you try to convert a value which can hold "true", "false" or "no value" to another one which can only hold "true" or "false".

You can tell it to map from nullable `Value`:

```
var mc = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<InternalEntity, PublicEntity>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.PublicName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.InternalName))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Active, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Active.Value));
});
```

Note that it will throw an exception if source `Active` has no value (obviously).

If `Active` equal to `null` means "inactive", then you can just use `??` operator:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Active, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Active.Value ?? false));
```

But why would you need a nullable at all then? :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, seems like you've got it wrong... (src => src.Active.Value) - src lambda parameter is InternalEntity there, so i cant run .Active on non-nullable property.

Comment: @FCR Oh, I see. I was misguided by your "// setup bool? -> bool projection somehow" comment. It is actually "bool -> bool?". Nice to hear that you have managed to solve it :)